# Is there an official term for long, unpunctuated sentences?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, writing-style, literature

after reading a recent thread on this topic (see here: [What would you call the stylistic omission of punctuation?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/421224/what-would-you-call-the-stylistic-omission-of-punctuation/421257)) I found that answers such as 'stream of consciousness' and 'run-on sentences' simply did not fit the examples which I had in mind.
For instance, this quote from 'The Bell Jar' by Sylvia Plath:

'But each time I would get the cord so tight I could feel a rushing in my ears and a flush of blood in my face my hands would weaken and let go, and I would be all right again.'

Evidently, the lack of punctuation (up until the comma) is used to create a tone of panic, the comma acting as a breath to break up this building anxiety. However, is there a specific term for this? Or would I have to explain the sentence's construction clunkily in order for the point to come across?

Any opinions or answers would be much appreciated.

Comment: Sylvia was attempting to commit poetry. It’s really poor style. However, the best word to describe writing in that style is *dramatic*; you can add phrases like *tension-building* and *breathy* and *dynamic* until the cow come home, …

Comment: … if you’re writing a review, *use your own words* but simply describing what she’s done and your impression of her purpose is probably more important than assigning a technical term to it. In other words, *something along the lines of* e.g. *Plath’s choice to omit most punctuation in/from this sentence builds a sense of headlong flight and urgency, …* etc. etc.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the figure of speech of polysyndeton or that of accumulation could provide a (partial) answer to your question. 
See, for example, Dante Alighieri:

> "E mangia e beve e dorme e veste panni" 
>   (Inferno, Canto XXXIII)

Answer (score 0):

Enjambment

noun

(in verse) the continuation of a sentence without a pause beyond the end of a line, couplet, or stanza.

Comment: Reference is needed to substantiate such an answer.